# Pivot SQL with top 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table, with scan data in rows.

I want to pivot the dataset, with the first scan in each phase_key.
[image]

Into this:

[image]

I use this sql:

```
select 

    d.shipment_id,
    d.carrier_reference,
    e.phase_key,
    e.event,
    CONVERT(DATETIME,e.time) AS ScanDate

from 
    data d
    inner join event e on d.id = e.data_id
where
shipment_id = '99156136'

order by e.time asc
```

I have tried using the suggested sql. (adding 1 id, to verify format. But it loads without the code suggested from @gotqn.

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME([phase_key]) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [phase_key])
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [phase_key]
        FROM data d
        inner join event e on d.id = e.data_id
        
) DS ([phase_key]);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT shipment_id
          ,phase_key
          ,time
    FROM data d
inner join event e on d.id = e.data_id

where
shipment_id = "99156136"
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([time]) FOR [phase_key] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

But after 2mins it still have not loaded the 1. id om trying as a sample.

Comment: `CONVERT(DATETIME,e.time)` seems odd. Is it not already a date and time data type..?

Comment: is shipmentid really a string? if it's INT, perhaps where
shipment_id = 99156136 is better

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME([phase_key]) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [phase_key])
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [phase_key]
    FROM [my_table]
) DS ([phase_key]);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT shipment_id
          ,phase_key
          ,ScanDate
    FROM [my_table]
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([ScanDate]) FOR [phase_key] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

Comment: How do I make a comment with code?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near ' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + '.

Comment: I don't get that error when parsing the above query, @DennisSchlein , which suggests you've changed something. What did you change?

Comment: Or a really old version?